# Handle Auto-redirects in Python Request module

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am using a website to decode some captcha images. I send some image via a session.post but the server takes some 2-3 seconds and then gives a 302 message which is basically a redirect message (this I see in the browser), but when I try to do the same using Python requests module, it gives me a 200 message which means that it successfully sent the message to the server.

What am I missing here? What should I add so that I get back the 302 response code which will have the url for further accessing the pages. Sample code and sample image attached.[image: image here]

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
headers = {'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',\
           'Referer':'http://www.to-text.net/',\
           'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36'}

data = {'action':"convert", 'ocr_lang':'eng',  'filename':"img_0.jpg"}

r1 = session.post('http://www.to-text.net/', files = data, headers = headers, allow_redirects=True)

print r1
```

I know that requests can handle auto-redirects, but when I try to access the same in

```
print r1.history
```

it's giving me an empty list.

This is what I see in the Chrome console when I use the form on the site:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Where are you sending the actual file? You are only sending the *filename*.

Comment: code and image reside in the same directory. hence i didn't add any path. i used chrome to see what does chrome sends to the server. these are the headers and the data fields that were being passed.

Comment: It won't just open the file for you, no. You need to open the file yourself and pass that in.

Answer (score 0):

You should **not** be setting the `Content-type` header; leave that to the `requests` module, as it needs to communicate the multipart boundary in that header.

You are also not actually sending any file data. Presumably you want to send the image file:

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
headers = {
   'Referer':'http://www.to-text.net/',
   'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36'
}

with open('img_0.jpg', 'rb') as imgfile:
    data = {
        'action': "convert",
        'ocr_lang': 'eng',
        'doc_file': ('img_0.jpg', imgfile, 'image/jpeg'),
    }

    r1 = session.post('http://www.to-text.net/', files=data, headers=headers)
```

See the [*POST a Multipart-Encoded File* section](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) of the *Quickstart* documentation.

You may also have to send an initial `GET` request to get a cookie set, and there may still be other checks the server makes against the request headers that you haven't yet provided. You'll have to experiment with those headers, a server is free to respond any way they like based on the exact headers and request body you send.

Comment: I used the code, which opens the file, and sends to the server, but the response is still the same. What I think is, the page is actually not re-directed, it remains on the same page, it just shows "converting....." for a short-while and then shows a new page.

Comment: Yes, the server is not giving you your converted file. Presumably they have a lot of anti-script measurements in place to prevent abuse.

Comment: ok. thanks. I just wanted to confirm if I was missing something.